# Cheap web hosting that supports php/mysql

Tags: mysql, php, web-hosting

Does anyone know where I can find web hosting that supports php/mysql?

I'm just using it to practice updating/changing live web sites, and to run code in an environment other than my XAMP stack on my thumb drive. It doesn't need to be fast or able to use a lot of bandwith, just somewhere I can play with code to sharpen my skill set

Comment: As just about every web host I've ever heard of supports PHP and MySQL I can only conclude that you've made absolutely no attempt to have a look for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the vote of confidence. I've looked at a number of places, but few have had any sort of clear cut answer as to how they support PHP/mySQL. Now this probably due to my own inexperience, and not knowing what to look for seeing as how I've never used web hosting before. Maybe I should go on some sort of question and answer type site and find out...

Comment: the problem here is that there really aren't good answers to your question other then to say Google for 'php mysql web hosting'.  There are thousands of hosting companies that support php+mysql.  There really isn't much long-term value for this Q&A site to duplicate content that is already on Google and changes frequently.  You also don't offer any real requirements that would lead me to favor one provider over another.  In your case, my suggestion is to just picky anything cheap and popular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hostgator comes to mind but you may want a VPS system not just a shared hosting account.

Check out VPS.net.  With a VPS you get full control over the LAMP stack which will probably be important to your development.

With a shared host, be sure to check how they run PHP. Some use PHP Suexec, fast-cgi, cgi-bin methods rather than mod_php which could impact your apps.

http://www.webhostingtalk.com/

is a good resource for all things web hosting.

Comment: +1 Closed as "Migrated to WHT by jeffatrackaid"

Answer (score 2):

I used [www.eukhost.com](http://www.eukhost.com) for a while and their services are excellent; you can even get SSH access to a jailshell prompt if you need to. Their support is top notch. I currently use a [www.memset.com](http://www.memset.com) VPS and it's absolutely excellent, no problems at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Kodingen](http://kodingen.com) - Its free (but in beta) and appears to be *extremely* developer friendly.

Comment: http://kodingen.com

Answer (score 1):

[Performancehosting.net](http://www.performancehosting.net/) offers very cheap shared hosting and support PHP and MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

(Sigh, can't vote up, can't comment...so I'll do the wrong thing and answer.)

I came here with the same question, looking at Kodingen mentioned above. It looks awesome - a very easy way to create servers, databases, fiddle in different languages etc. Oh, and free.